# Select item from drop down menu in C# using Selenium in web assembly - doesn't work

Tags: c#, html, selenium, automated-tests

I am working with some automated tests and I am using Selenium Web driver with that. I have wrote a script till now that can find the class but cannot select either one of the items in the drop down.

This is my script till now:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("loginOK")).Click();
Thread.Sleep(3000);
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id = \"content\"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]")).Click();
Thread.Sleep(3000);
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id= \"sec1272\"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/img")).Click();
Thread.Sleep(3000);
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("fm - s fm - off fm - focused"));
```

and I want to select one of the items below:

```
    <tbody>
    <tr class="row" oid="12" height="24"><td class="ln">Bujqesi, Zhvillim rural, Pyjet dhe kullotat, Natyra dhe Biodiversiteti</td></tr>
    <tr class="row-selected" oid="13" height="24"><td class="ln">Burime Njerezore</td></tr>
    <tr class="row" oid="9" height="24"><td class="ln">Administrimi dhe menaxhimi i institucioneve te arsimit parauniversitar</td></tr>
    <tr class="row" oid="14" height="24"><td class="ln">Ceshtje ligjore/Asete</td></tr>
    <tr class="row" oid="15" height="24"><td class="ln">Emergjencat Civile/Mbrojtja nga Zjarri</td></tr>
    <tr class="row" oid="10" height="24"><td class="ln">Hapesire Publike/Mjedis</td></tr>
    <tr class="row" oid="2" height="24"><td class="ln">Kerkesa/Ankesa te pergjithshme</td></tr>
    </tbody>
```

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: what does any of this have to do with web assembly?

Comment: You talk about a "drop down" but your HTML is just a table?

Comment: @Liam ok, but items are showed as a drop down

Answer (score 0):

So, how does one actually select the items in the drop down? I've never seen a table used as a dropdown. Are the events attached to the "tr" table row elements, or to the "td" cell elements?

Are you saying that your script provided finds the td element by the class name ("ln"), but what you really need is to select the parent element, which is the table row element?

Are you trying to select a specific row, or any of them will do? Let's assume you specifically want an option containing "Biodiversiteti".

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

List<IWebElement> options = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("tr")).ToList();
IWebElement selectOption = options.Find(x => x.FindElement(By.TagName("td")).Text.Contains("Biodiversiteti"));
selectOption.Click();
```